# I can´t connect to my raspi bitcoin rpc server

Tags: ssh, ping, cryptocurrency

I am running a bitcoin rpc server on my raspi and I can connect to it using local bitcoin-cli, but not externally from a windows on the same LAN. I tried installing ufw and disabling firewall on my raspi, and allowed tcp and udp connection to remote port 8332 on my windows, but that didn´t work. I can ping my raspi´s api from windows, but I can only get response from pinging my windows from raspi if I disable windows´ firewall. I don´t know what else to do.

I just noticed that if I put -rpcconnect=192.168.0.114 on bitcoin-cli argument it doesn´t connect, but if I put 127.0.0.1 it connects, and I am certain of the raspi´s ip is 192.168.0.114 from ifconfig result and also from ssh connection ( which works )

Comment: I know how to setup http/ftp/nas servers, but now I want to set up bitcoin servers for two reasons: (1) My bad friends will LOL at me if I don't have a money making" server/machine. (2) Learn more block chain things (I know nothing about it) to survive, since IPlv6 and 5G are coming. Question: I have 4 Rpi4Bs in my home network.  Do I need to TCP/UDP break the fire wall to meet other money making guys?   https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)

Comment: hey @tlfong01 I just found out the issue, check my answer!

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that I need these lines on bitcoin.conf to access rpc from outside localhost:

> rpcbind=192.168.0.114
>
> rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0

or start bitcoind or bitcoin-qt with -rcpbind=xxx and -rpcallowip=xxx

Apparently if you don´t bind your ip to your lan ip, it will only work with local connections, and rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0 is not recommended because it opens up for anyone to connect, so I´ll probably change that but if you don´t, make sure your password is secure enough.

Comment: Hi @Badjano, Nice to know you solved your problem. I will remember your warnings by heart, even though I don't understand, what do you mean by binding "global IP“ to "local ip" etc.  You seem to have a way to get a static IP, which I have recently given up, because I found out static IP is expensive.  I know very little about networking, bridge, access point, etc.  So I am googling and wiking to read more.  I am also studying python tcp and udp modules, so to dig a tunnel to jail break firewall outside, to meet other blocking chain money making gangs.

Comment: the ip I had to bind was my local ip on my private network, not a global ip ( which would be the one on my router ). I could forward the local port on to a global port through my router, but I don´t want to do that. There are 3 levels of access here, a localhost, which is only visible on the same computer, a private network level, which other computers on your network can see, and a global network, which is visibible from anyone in the internet. I wanted to be visible on my private network only.

Comment: What are these lines mean? Where they are located? Please don't answer in a comment. Instead edit your answer and put it there.

Comment: @Ingo see if that helps!